# INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR PayPal REST API https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment

Tags: paypal

Using "LIVE" credentials, I'm getting an INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR accepting a credit card payment, using this resource: https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment.  Same error happens on the web and via cURL. NOTE: This does **not** happen in SANDBOX only LIVE.  See steps to recreate below.  For this post, I had to add a space in "http s" as I cannot submit more than 2 links.

1. Get an OAuth token (substitute username/password in LIVE_USER_ID:LIVE_PASSWORD

   curl http s://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token -H "Accept: application/json" -H  "Accept-Language: en_US" -u "LIVE_USER_ID:LIVE_PASSWORD" -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
2. No problem getting a token using LIVE credentials.  Add the token to the following request to the resource:

   ```
   curl -v http s://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment \
   ```

   -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
   -H "Authorization:Bearer YK.GUHkGhBAQgGgGkilvHoL7DdE9SVq.IDl-mRwAZeM" \
   -d '{
     "intent": "sale",
     "payer": {
       "payment_method": "credit_card",
       "funding_instruments": [
         {
           "credit_card": {
             "number": "5500005555555559",
             "type": "mastercard",
             "expire_month": 12,
             "expire_year": 2018,
             "cvv2": 111,
             "first_name": "Joe",
             "last_name": "Shopper"
           }
         }
       ]
     },
     "transactions": [
       {
         "amount": {
           "total": "0.01",
           "currency": "USD"
         },
         "description": "This is the payment transaction description."
       }
     ]
   }'

"name":"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","message":"An internal service error has occurred","information_link":"http_s://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","debug_id":"525bfb7a6382a"}johnruffin:~ johnruffin$ 
Thoughts???

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for bringing this issue to our attention.  I've opened an internal bug with the payments rest api development team.  From the debug id provided I see that the credit card is being refused.  In the future the error message from this scenario will fall under this error condition: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#CREDIT_CARD_REFUSED

Please try a another/valid credit card to verify.

Comment: would it be fixed at all?

Answer (score -3):

Looks like the URL is not well formed. It's https and not http s as provided above.

Tried the calls now, it works fine. Please check and confirm.

Comment: As noted in the original post, the url was listed as "http s" with added space only to prevent SO from disallowing more than 2 urls.