# PayPal Rest API Internal Service Error

Tags: paypal

Occasionally we receive an Internal service error as a response from REST API.

Here is the latest one:
{"name":"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","message":"An internal service error has occurred","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","debug_id":"863be52d8dddb"}

What is the reason for this error?

Comment: may be this is something that may clarify the issue [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197151/internal-service-error-paypal-rest-api-https-api-paypal-com-v1-payments-paymen][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197151/internal-service-error-paypal-rest-api-https-api-paypal-com-v1-payments-paymen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should contact PayPal Merchant Technical Support (MTS) and provide them with the `debug_id` that is returned:
https://ppmts.custhelp.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you are making CC payment, change your credit card https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/750